# Python error "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm keep getting this error when I execute `annuity_rate(5, 100, 510)` or I try negative values. How can I fix this?

It works well with a large number but somehow not working for negative and small numbers .

```py
def pv_annuity(r, n, pmt):
    """ Return the present value of an annuity of pmt to be received
        each period for n periods"""
    pv = pmt * (1 - (1 + r) ** (-n)) / r

    return pv


def annuity_rate(n, pmt, pv):
    """ return the rate of interest required to amortize the pv in n periods
        with equal periodic payments of pmt"""

    rate_low, rate_high = 0, 1

    while True:
        rate = (rate_high + rate_low) / 2
        #print('trying rate', rate)
        test_pv = pv_annuity(rate, n, pmt)
        #print(test_pv)
        if abs(pv - test_pv) <= 0.01:
            break

        if test_pv > pv:
            rate_low = (rate_high + rate_low) / 2

        if test_pv < pv:
            rate_high = (rate_high + rate_low) / 2

    return rate
```

Comment: when `rate` is `0`, you divide by zero in `pv_annuity()`.

Comment: Your loop iterates 1074 times, reducing the rate to very small float point, until it rounds to 0 and fails in the division.

Comment: @Barmar Im using python3...

Comment: I removed my comment, it's not related to that. calestini identified the problem.

Comment: @calestini how can i fix this ?

Comment: if your calculations are supposed to behave that way, then just exit your while loop when rate becomes 0. `if rate==0: return 0`. Have you tested your code for other values, are you getting the right results?

Comment: @calestini Yes it works for other values but it only fails the test when i try small numbers or negative values. I cant just return 0 because rate can go below 0

Comment: I don't know if that affects the results but maybe you can add a really really small and arbitrary amount to rate like this `rate = (rate_high + rate_low) / 2 + 10e-32`. Using that method `annuity_rate(5, 100, 510) == 2.1769424370794323e-16`, but I have no idea if that is the result expected.

Comment: I echo @accdias comment. Ideally you can create a very small variable called `epsylon`, and if it becomes lower than that, you force it to equal that, or add to it, until it reverses to negative.

Comment: I guess it works because the resulting `pv` for that `rate` almost hits those `510` originals: `509.99190686668885`.

Comment: If all you want is reliable financial functions, take a look at [NumPy Financial functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.financial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using your example of annuity_rate(5, 100, 510):

- The rate_high will keep decreasing no matter what conditions are met, since each loop starts with division of the rate by 2.
- pv_test gets higher than the pv, then will convert into zero when the rate is so low (test_pv = pmt * (1 - (1 + r) ** (-n)) / r) since the nominator is decreasing faster than the denominator.
- After that, the rate keeps decreasing with zero test_pv, at an even faster rate (rate_high = (rate_high + rate_low) / 2).
- The rate finally reaches 5e-324, and upon further reduction, it becomes almost zero, leading to ( pmt * (1 - (1 + r) ** (-n)) / **r**) being a division by zero.

**Suggested solution:**
Change the payment in (pv_annuity(rate, n, **pmt**)), it should reflect the changes in the rate.